# Node - Express - Session not working?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, passport.js

So I'm stuck as to why this isn't working. Whenever I use the cookie for maxAge, it just doesn't allow me to login. It redirects me to /, so the callback is working but the session data is lost for some reason. Can anybody assist me?

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb');

var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var app = express();




// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({
    secret: '1234567890QWERT',
    cookie: {maxAge: 30}
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(app.router);

var dbc;
var User;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/redacted', function(err, db) {
    dbc = db;
    User = dbc.collection('users');
});


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {

    User.findOne({ email: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (password == user.password) {
            console.log("Login success!");

            // Allows us to keep a log of when the user logs in in:
            //     user['loggedin'][]
            // db.users.update({email: ""}, { $push : {loggedin: new Date()} } )



            if(!err) done(null, user );
        }
        else done(err, null)  
    }); 
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, {
      id: user["_id"],
      name: user["name"],
      email: user["email"],
      registered: user["registered"],
      password: user["password"]
   });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log(id);

    User.find({_id: id._id}, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });

});

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
}

app.get('/', routes.index);



// User stuff
app.get('/login', login.get);
app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',
                                   failureRedirect: '/login?m=fail'
                               })
);
app.get('/register', register.get);
app.post('/register', register.post);

app.get('/logout', function(req, res){
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your session cookie is set to last 30ms.

Per [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie), maxAge sets the expiration date of the cookie in ms.

Change `cookie: {maxAge: 30}` to something like `cookie: {maxAge: 24*60*60*1000}` for a longer-lasting session cookie.